# Access children of items inside a Lightning Component

Tags: javascript, controller, tabs, salesforce-lightning

I have my lightning component set up like this:

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="opts" type="List" default="['Tyler Dahle','Molly Demouser','Penny Demouser', 'Ted Demouser']"/>
<lightning:tabset aura:id="tabBar" variant="scoped" selectedTabId="none">
    <lightning:tab aura:id="ownerTab">
        <aura:set attribute="label">
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:groups"/>
        </aura:set>
        <lightning:select name="users" label="Select Users/Groups/Resources:">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.opts}" var="option">
                <option>{!option}</option>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>
        <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Enable" name="Enable User Filter" checked="true"/>
        <lightning:button class="closeUser" variant="base" iconName="utility:close" onclick="{!c.closeTabContent}"/>
    </lightning:tab>
  </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

Then I initialize in a visualforce page like:

```
$Lightning.use("c:filterBar", function(){
                    $Lightning.createComponent("c:userTab", {label: ""}, "filterTabStrip");    
                });
```

And it displays, and I can click through my tabs and everything. However, I have the button with the 'x' displayed in it in my tab content. When the user clicks this I want the tab content to close again, because right now, once you open a tab, a tab is always open.

I tried using component.find('ownerTab') in a the controller, but that returns undefined. component.find('tabBar') returns a tab bar, then I can do .get('selectedTabId') on my tab bar and it returns the correct Id, but I can't figure out what to do to find the tab, then set its class to 'slds-tabs--scoped__content slds-hide' when the 'x' is clicked (that class I just listed is the class given to content in the html page, where 'hide' changes to 'show' when content is displayed).

So I am largely wondering how I go about accessing the tab from the controller (not the tabset, but the tab), and how I might close the content. I will attempt to change it's class once I figure out how to access the tab, but I have a feeling that won't work.....

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

once you navigate to other component you don't have direct link to communicate,

1. In order to communicate between aura:components we use aura:events
2. In order to communicate between aura:component and vf page we need to go with postmessage javascript funtion,  and event listeners to handle these messages.